# Combine Date and Time of DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#

I need to format `DateTimeOffset` the same way as windows regional settings.
Here is what I did so far:

```
var strDate = string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                    myDateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern), 
                    myDateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern));
```

Is there a shorter way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even shorter:

```
var strDate = string.Format("{0:d} {0:T}", myDateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the "[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)" you can see you get the same effect by doing `"d"` and `"T"`

```
var strDate = string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                    myDateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime().ToString("d"), 
                    myDateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime().ToString("T"));
```

Using those two strings will return the culture specific short date and long time formatted values.

Comment: You mean `d` and `T`. Will `ToLocalTime()` ensure to grab `currentCulture`?

Comment: The `.ToLocalTime()` returns a `DateTime` object, that object has no culture tied to it at all. The thing that grabs the culture is the [`ToString(string)` function](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,5088b43558351160) and that function will use `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` which internally uses `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` ([`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` also returns the value for `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1f5907384ac6bb55))